# Safari tries to https on localhost

Tags: macos, https, safari

I was testing my ruby on rails app on a Mac and tried to open `"https://localhost:3000"` which obviously doesn't work. Unfortunately now safari refuses to try anything else when I type in `locahost:3000`. It will automatically add "https://" and come back to me with an error. How can I make it stop?

It's safari 8.0.2 and OS X Yosemite.

Thanks a lot. It's driving me insane

Answer (score 0):

Of course, minutes after I posted this I did find out what the issue was. I tried other browsers and had the same issue - which made me sceptical. I found out that Ruby on Rails app I tried force an ssl connection to be established. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this problem and for who it isn't a server side issue, I have found a workaround. Edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add an alias for localhost, like so

```
127.0.0.1 lokalhost
```

Then use http://lokalhost:3000 to access your project.

Answer (score -3):

If you know better than Safari, simply tell it the full address:

```
http://localhost:3000
```